# TypeScript throwing a nonsense exception

Tags: typescript

TypeScript throws an error for this:

```
const tryAddress = async (add?: string, postcode?: string) => {
  if (postcode?.length < 5) {
   // ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Object is possibly 'undefined'.
```

But not this:

```
const tryAddress = async (add?: string, postcode?: string) => {
  if (postcode && postcode.length < 5) {
```

I thought the `?.` shorthand was supposed to allow us to prevent writing conditions like the one below. Am I missing something?

Edit:

I got it! It's because it simplifies to

```
(undefined < 5)
```

But, is there a better way to write these conditionals? Because I write them all the time!

Comment: `postcode?.length` prevent it from throwing exception when `postcode` is undefined. The expression still resolve to undefined. What do you mean for `undefined < 5`?

Comment: Maybe you should change the title to be more accurate (it's a valid exception) and less vague (you are looking for a terser way to write a particular sort of conditional).

Comment: What do you want to see happen when `postcode === ""`?  Note that it will fail the `postcode && postcode.length < 5` check, even though `postcode.length < 5` is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is slightly misleading. This occurs when using `undefined` in a *comparison*. The following has the same problem:

```
if (undefined < 5) {
```

A more precise error message would be:

> This is possibly undefined, and so cannot be compared sensibly

After all, what would you expect

```
undefined < 5
```

to evaluate to? Would *everyone* reading the code come to the same conclusion? Not necessarily - and thus TS forbids it.

Don't use optional chaining when comparing, because `undefined` doesn't make sense in that context. Your original:

```
if (postcode && postcode.length < 5) {
```

is the clearest approach, and the one I'd prefer.

Comment: I used demorgans on it in the end: `if (!postcode || postcode.length >= 5)`

Answer (score 2):

It's a perfectly sensible error.

`postcode?.length` evaluates to an `undefined | number`.

The `undefined` member of that union type is incompatible with `<`.

`postcode && postcode.length < 5` works because by the time the right side is evaluated, the possibility of `postcode.length` being `undefined` has been eliminated, so it's type is simply `number`, which can be compared just fine.